# Request repetido

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, ajax

Desde JS hago una llamada mediante Ajax a un fichero php para borrar un registro de una tabla.

```
function eliminar_archivo(id_a_eliminar) {

    $('img[data-hook="eliminar-doc"]').attr('src', './library/images/trash.svg');
    $('img[data-hook="eliminar-doc"]').prop('disabled', false);
    console.log(id_a_eliminar);
    $.post({
        url: "./site/xhr/_share/eliminar_doc.php?",
        data: {'id_doc': id_a_eliminar},
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function () {
        },
    }).done(function () {
        _llenar_tabla();
    }).fail(function (msg) {
        console.log('FAIL');
    }).always(function (msg) {
        $('.borrado-doc').hide('slow');
    });
}
```

El asunto es que la primera vez lo hace bien, pero si vuelvo a pulsar sobre la imagen que desencadena el evento sin recargar la página, me manda por duplicado, triplicado, etc el request. ¿qué estoy haciendo mal?. Espero haberme explicado bien. Muchas gracias

[image: Aquí podéis ver las repeticiones tras pulsar por tercera vez]

Desde aquí hago la llamada a la función. Al hacer click en una imagen le paso la id que va a borrar.

```
$('body').on("click",'#confirmar-borrado-doc', function (e) {
        var $boton_eliminar = $(this),
            id_a_eliminar = $boton_eliminar.data('id_doc');
        eliminar_archivo(id_a_eliminar);
    });
```

Comment: ¿Probaste `$.ajax` en vez de `$.post`? Además puedes usar `fetch()` si no hay mucho problema

Comment: Sí, lo probé con $.ajax, $.post, $.get... Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Cómo ejecutas la función? ¿Usas un `addEventListener('click'...)`? Edita la pregunta para agregar esa parte del código.

Comment: Añadido. Hago click en una imagen y desde ahí llamo a la función con el id que tiene esa imagen.

Comment: Es muy poco el código que muestras y no queda muy claro el uso que le das al botón, si es para eliminar un solo elemento o múltiples y, si es el segundo caso, estás repitiendo IDs que deberían ser únicos. ¿Dónde aparece el botón, en cada fila o fuera de la tabla? Edita nuevamente la pregunta para responder las dudas y agregar un ejemplo de tu HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré el problema. En otra parte del código estaba cargando a cada llamada un nuevo evento al botón, con lo que iba teniendo dos, tres, cuatro... eventos en el mismo botón. Gracias por vuestro interés